# Nested list comprehension using if and for

Tags: python, numpy, list-comprehension

I was trying to easily output the positive indices of an array using `numpy`. I was able to get the following:

```
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(1)
a = np.random.sample(100) - 0.5
a_pos_idx = []
for i in range(len(a)):
  if a[i] > 0:
    a_pos_idx += [i]
```

This gives me the positive indices in the array `a` inside the array `a_pos_idx`. However, I wanted to do this more simply (in a readable one-liner) using list comprehension. This is what I came up with:

```
a_pos_idx = [i if a[i] > 0 for i in range(len(a))]
```

However, this gives me an invalid syntax error. Is there any way to create such nested for loops in Python?

Comment: `a_pos_idx = [i for i in range(len(a)) if a[i] > 0]`

Comment: `a_pos_idx = [idx for idx, i in enumerate(a) if i > 0]`

Comment: `np.where(a > 0)`

Comment: You shouldn't be using numpy like this at all. You want to use `numpy.where(a > 0)`. Otherwise, you might as well not use numpy.

Comment: What do you mean by that? As in I shouldn't be using numpy to generate random numbers?

Answer (score 2):

The list comprehension needs to place the filter (`if a[i] > 0`) at the end.

```python
[i for i in range(len(a)) if a[i] > 0]
```

Since you are using numpy, you can use the built-in [`where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) function as follows:

```python
np.where(a > 0)
```

#### Full example

```
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(1)
a = np.random.sample(100) - 0.5
a_pos_idx = []
for i in range(len(a)):
  if a[i] > 0:
    a_pos_idx += [i]

print(f"For loop:\n{a_pos_idx}")

a_pos_idx_2 = [i for i in range(len(a)) if a[i] > 0]
print(f"\nList comphrehension:\n{a_pos_idx_2}")

a_pos_idx_3, *_ = np.where(a > 0)
print(f"\nnumpy filter:\n{a_pos_idx_3}")
```

**Output:**

```
For loop:
[1, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 20, 21, 23, 24, 25, 29, 32, 33, 34, 36, 37, 39, 40, 41, 43, 46, 51, 56, 58, 59, 62, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 73, 76, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 85, 87, 88, 89, 91, 93, 96, 97, 99]

List comphrehension:
[1, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 20, 21, 23, 24, 25, 29, 32, 33, 34, 36, 37, 39, 40, 41, 43, 46, 51, 56, 58, 59, 62, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 73, 76, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 85, 87, 88, 89, 91, 93, 96, 97, 99]

numpy filter:
[ 1  9 11 13 15 17 20 21 23 24 25 29 32 33 34 36 37 39 40 41 43 46 51 56
 58 59 62 65 66 67 68 69 70 73 76 78 79 80 81 82 85 87 88 89 91 93 96 97
 99]
```

Comment: Note that `np.where` returns a tuple of arrays, so you'd either have to grab the result as the zeroth element of that tuple or do some unpacking in the assignment like `a_pos_idx, *_ = np.where(a > 0)`.